# Trigger event on component from another component

Tags: react-native

I am unsure how to trigger an event in my `TouchableOpacity` component that will target the `TextInput` component. I'd just like to be able to allow the user to type in a multiline area and click a button when they are finished, so that they are able to save their text (similar to how the iOS Notes app functions).

```js
<View>
    <View>
        <Text>Notes</Text>
        {typing && 
        <TouchableOpacity
            onPress={() => {
            //blur() the textinput here
            }}
        >
            <Text>Done</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        }
    </View>
    <View>
        <TextInput 
            multiline={true}
            textAlignVertical='top'
            value={text}
            onChangeText={(text) => {
            }}
            onFocus={setTyping(true)}
        />
    </View>
</View>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only need to access the text inside the same file, store your text in state in your component.

```js
  const [text, setText] = useState('');

  ...

  <TouchableOpacity
    // not sure what you want to do with the text here, but it'll be available in the `text` variable
    onPress={() => saveNote(text)}
    ...
  

  <TextInput
    onChangeText={newText => setText(newText)
    // or more simply
    onChangeText={setText}
    ...
  />
```

The text input will automatically blur when you touch the Touchable.

If you need the text available in other files, have a look into React Context or look up state management libraries for React Native.